# Regarding rebuild process

Tags: windows, rebuild

In the process of rebuilding my XP desktop machine.  It has 2 hard drives. I want to wipe the first, re-install Windows on it, then clean the 2nd hard drive from the fresh install.

So all I have to do is:

- Insert install disc, boot
- Choose partition I am talking about (i.e. first hard drive)
- Format and install on it
- Boot, 2nd hard drive, will load - unchanged.

Does this look correct?  Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: This would be better asked on Superuser: http://superuser.com/

Comment: Make sure you backup anything you want to save from the first drive. Once you wipe it and install Windows, all will be gone. Might want to disconnect the second drive while you install, just to be safe and lessen any chance of data loss on the second drive.

Answer (score 1):

if all you want to do is reinstall windows on one hard drive and deletes its contents then that is PERFECT. AS for the second drive. it will be as you left it unchanged and you can do anything you please with it.

good luck.